# How to know which Ubuntu I'm booting on

Tags: grub2, clonezilla

I have used CloneZilla to clone my Ubuntu partition to another partition of the same HDD. Now I have noticed that I have two Ubuntu in the grub menu. How Can get only one Ubuntu in the grub menu? Or how to know the original Ubuntu and the cloned one so I won't boot in the cloned one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution for this would be renaming the grub boot entry so that you can identify from the boot menu to which **Ubuntu** you've to chose right?

So the easiest way to achieve is here:

1. First install **grub-customizer** in any of the Ubuntu, best you chose the **first** from the list. Execute these commands in terminal:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
   ```
2. Open **grub-customizer** and rename the list of your OS under <kbd>List configuration</kbd> tab. You've to **right click** and chose **rename** option:

   [image]
3. Clsoe the window, it will prompt for saving etc.. Chose <kbd>Save & Quit</kbd> option.
4. Update **grub** and restart your system.

   ```
   sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
   ```

From the next boot if you get the changes reflected it means that you've done. Obviously if you don't get any changes then you've to do the same but this time you've to chose **second** from the list. Hope you can understand what I'm saying. :)